# Get all directories into Folder

Tags: java

I want to create Java program which gets all processes from /proc directory and lists the memory which they consume. To do this all directories which start with number must be checked with Java and then I want to read the value from the `stats` and get the values how much the process consumes memory. Can you help me to do this with Java?

```
File file = new File("/proc");
String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directories));
```

As final step I would like to insert the values into Java collection I order to remember the properties.

P.S Can you tell me how I can extend the code this way:

1. Loop into the /proc filesystem and get only the folders which start with number.
   Open the contend of the file into each folder which starts with number and read the content of the file `stats`.
2. Get the content for the first line.

Comment: If you're interested in the File objects themselves, you should rather use File#listFiles(FileFilter). But apart from that, it looks correct. What's your problem?

Comment: Can you help me to add the needed functionality into my code?

Comment: What exact help do you need from us?

Comment: Its no clear what you're after .